# How can I disable some type of data fetching data database column in Database(mysql)

Tags: mysql

I'm returning some data from database, I have type of bridges like (minimum,maximam,avarage,Culvert ) so this all the bridges have some records, all the data coming from data base so I don't want to fetch Culvert records in the bridge type. How can I do this in the query...

Below my query is there:

```
    $qry = "select bm.bridge_id, state_code, zone, type_of_road, road_no, cumul_bridge_code, bm.longitude, bm.latitude, type_of_bridge, age_of_bridge, transaction_datetime, no_of_inventory_done, no_of_inspection_done, no_of_testing_done, no_of_repair_done, inventory_status, inspection_status, testing_status, repair_status from bridge_master bm, bridge_details id where bm.bridge_id = id.bridge_id group by 1 order by road_no, zone, bridge_id, transaction_datetime limit $start, $num_of_rows";
```

Ex: Below is records is there, so there is ( Type of Bridge :  Culvert) Record is there so I don't want this Record how can i do this query please help some one I'm new in mysqli Thanks...

```
**Bridge Details**

**Record 1:**

Bridge ID      :  KAKA-01T024ZZ0130340123
State          :  Karnataka
Zone           :  Bangalore Central (Koramangala)
Age of Bridge  :  41 years to 50 years Yrs
Type of Bridge :  Culvert
Date           :  2022-02-03 11:20:50

**Record 2:**

Bridge ID      :  KAKA-01T024ZZ0130340123
State          :  Karnataka
Zone           :  Bangalore Central (Koramangala)
Age of Bridge  :  41 years to 50 years Yrs
Type of Bridge :  Maximam
Date           :  2022-02-03 11:20:50
```

Comment: FYI, your database is called mysql

Comment: Hi   Your Common Sense,,,, my database is mysqli

Comment: [The mysqli PHP extension is a PHP database driver. Not to be confused with MySQL database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli)